# Gui tool for configuring squid, or maybe recommend another tool for caching

Tags: web-server, internet

I have a very slow wan connection, so I would like to cache as much web content as I can. I don't want to spend hours and hours configuring it, so I was wondering if there is some, easy to configure web caching proxy server.

P.S. It would be preferable that the download be less than 15 MB, to install on Ubuntu server. I already have an apt caching server so as long as the package itself is not that large it should not be a problem.

P.P.S. sorry about the tags, didn't have enough rep to do better.

Comment: Even if such a tool existed, it would take at least the same amount of work to set it up as configuring Squid directly.

Comment: I added a Squid tag for you

Comment: Did you look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/squidgui/ ? Not much info there, but 58 downloads this week.

Answer (score 1):

I found [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/), tried it out and it looks pretty good. It has a nice interface for configuring squid.

It does many other things (besides squid) and is about 20 megabytes to download but it was worth the download.